# Separate element for each database row not showing up

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with a website that i am making. It has a bar with a categories button.When you hover over  it, a menu appears with all the categories from my SQL Database. I want to make another menu pop up when you hover over each category showing their respective sub-categories. My problem is that the subcategories menu will not pop up at all. The PHP and everything works just fine. Here is my code for it:

```css
.categorii {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: Oswald;
  text-align: right;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: url('pictures/buton_categorii.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .dropdown-categorii:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
 }
 .dropdown-categorii {
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 11%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .dropdown-content-categorii {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-top: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 3;
  font-family: Ubuntu2;
  color: #003e91;
  animation-name: slideIn-categ;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
 }
 @keyframes slideIn-categ {
  from {margin-top: 20px; opacity: 0;}
  to { margin-top: 38px; opacity: 1;}
 }
 .dropdown-categorii:hover .dropdown-content-categorii {
  display: block;
 }
 .categoriesep {
  display: block;
  font-family: Ubuntu2;
  color: #003e91;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: none;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .categoriesep-content {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 5;
  font-family: Ubuntu2;
  color: #003e91;
  animation-name: slideIn-categsep;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
 }
 .categoriesep:hover .categoriesep-content {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-categorii">
   <button class="categorii" id="categorii">CATEGORII</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content-categorii" id="dropdown-content-categorii">
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=+PLASE+INSECTE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep"> PLASE INSECTE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ACCESORII+CONSTR.CASA+INTERIOR"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ACCESORII CONSTR CASA INTERIOR</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ACCESORII+CONSTRUCTII"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ACCESORII CONSTRUCTII</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ACCESORII+INSTALATII+SANITARE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ACCESORII INSTALATII SANITARE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ACCESORII.SCULE+PTR.LEMN"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ACCESORII SCULE PTR LEMN</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ADEZIVI"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ADEZIVI</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=AMBALARE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">AMBALARE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=BOILERE%2CRADIATOARE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">BOILERE RADIATOARE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=CHIMICE+SI+TEHNICE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">CHIMICE SI TEHNICE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=CORPURI+DE+ILUMINAT"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">CORPURI DE ILUMINAT</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ECHIPAMENT+PROTECTIE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ECHIPAMENT PROTECTIE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ELECTROCASNICE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ELECTROCASNICE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ELECTRONICE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ELECTRONICE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=FERESTRE+PVC+SI+ALUMINIU"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">FERESTRE PVC SI ALUMINIU</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=FERONERIE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">FERONERIE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=FERONERIE+PVC+SI+ALUMINIU"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">FERONERIE PVC SI ALUMINIU</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=FIXARI+CONEXPAND"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">FIXARI CONEXPAND</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=FIXARI+CU+DIBLURI"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">FIXARI CU DIBLURI</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=GENERALE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">GENERALE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=GRADINA.SCULE.CASA.SOBE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">GRADINA SCULE CASA SOBE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=INSTALATII+APA"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">INSTALATII APA</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=MATERIALE+SI+ACCES.PTR.INST.ELECTR."><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">MATERIALE SI ACCES PTR INST ELECTR </button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=MOBILIER"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">MOBILIER</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=OBIECTE+SANITARE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">OBIECTE SANITARE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=PLASE+INSECTE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">PLASE INSECTE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=PRELUCRARI+ASCHIERE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">PRELUCRARI ASCHIERE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=SCULE+DEBITARE%2CSLEF.POLIZARE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">SCULE DEBITARE SLEF POLIZARE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=SCULE+PTR.BETON%2CZIDARIE%2CSTICLA"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">SCULE PTR BETON ZIDARIE STICLA</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=SCULE%2BUNELTE.ACCESORII"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">SCULE UNELTE ACCESORII</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=STRUCTURI+LEMN"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">STRUCTURI LEMN</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=SURUB.+AUTOFORANTE%2CAUTOFILETANTE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">SURUB  AUTOFORANTE AUTOFILETANTE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=SURUBURI+LEMN"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">SURUBURI LEMN</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=TEHNICE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">TEHNICE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=TEVI%2BFITINGURI"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">TEVI FITINGURI</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=UNELTE+DE+MANA"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">UNELTE DE MANA</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=UNELTE+ELECTRICE"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">UNELTE ELECTRICE</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=USI+DIVERSE%2CAL%2CPVC%2CGARAJ"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">USI DIVERSE AL PVC GARAJ</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
         <a href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=VAR+LAVABIL%2CPASTA%2CVOPSEA%2CDILUANT"><button class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">VAR LAVABIL PASTA VOPSEA DILUANT</button></a>
     <div class="categoriesep-content" id="categoriesep-content">This will be content</div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT: I have updated the snippet so it includes that parsed HTML. As you can see, the main menu works just fine, but if i hover over one of the categories(created by PHP), nothing happens, when it should be another menu that pops up (With the class `categoriesep-content`).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: We will need more info on how far you've gotten. Is it the PHP failing or the CSS? When you view the page source (not inspect, but actually view source), have the database rows been written into the HTML as intended? What does that output HTML markup look like, and is it valid HTML? If PHP is failing itself, have you enabled error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script, and check php error logs.

Comment: sorry for the lack of information. The page looks as it should regarding the categories, all of them are showing up. What is failing is the CSS. I can't get the subcategories menu to show. Not even a rectangle when i hover over an element from the database.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend editing your post so that it is clear your issue is with the CSS, remove the PHP tag and post the real HTML source output after PHP processing is complete. People with CSS expertise will help more readily.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i have edited the post!